# generate group col using names in two cols (reflecting ties)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, networkx

In python, how can I create a column whose values represent groups, where groups are based on ties indicated by the names of persons (col1) and associates (col2)?

The dataset is longitudinal / panel / time-series. There are many missing values in the associate column. But for some persons, there are many values in the associate col. Associates are probably linked through persons, and this is what I hope the group column will clarify. I.e. there are only needed as many groups, so as to group persons that can be linked through other persons somehow.

How do I go about handling this? It seems to involve at least one loop/iteration, which I am not awfully skilled at writing.

| index | person | associate | desired column: group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 | - | 1 |
| 2 | name1 | - | 1 |
| 3 | name1 | - | 1 |
| 1 | name2 | name1 | 1 |
| 2 | name2 | name4 | 1 |
| 3 | name2 | name3 | 1 |
| 1 | name3 | - | 1 |
| 2 | name3 | - | 1 |
| 3 | name3 | - | 1 |
| 1 | name4 | - | 1 |
| 2 | name4 | - | 1 |
| 3 | name4 | - | 1 |
| 1 | name5 | - | - |
| 2 | name5 | - | - |
| 3 | name5 | - | - |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the [`connected_components`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html) in a graph, use [`networkx`](https://networkx.org), then [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) you groups:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='person', target='associate')
G.remove_node('-')

groups = {n: i if len(g)>1 else '-' for i, g in
          enumerate(nx.connected_components(G), start=1)
          for n in g}

df['group'] = df['person'].map(groups)
```

Output:

```
    index person associate group
0       1  name1         -     1
1       2  name1         -     1
2       3  name1         -     1
3       1  name2     name1     1
4       2  name2     name4     1
5       3  name2     name3     1
6       1  name3         -     1
7       2  name3         -     1
8       3  name3         -     1
9       1  name4         -     1
10      2  name4         -     1
11      3  name4         -     1
12      1  name5         -     -
13      2  name5         -     -
14      3  name5         -     -
```

Your data as a graph:

[image: graph]

Comment: fantastic! (literally). The missing values are NaN on my end, so `G.remove_node('-')` does not have the intended effect. Any suggestions are much appreciated, thanks. I will set the question to answered, though.

Comment: Yes, then you can modify the code to have `G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df.dropna(subset=['person', 'associate']), source='person', target='associate') ; groups = {n: i for i, g in enumerate((g for g in nx.connected_components(G) if len(g)>1), start=1) for n in g}`